# Discord.py kickall command

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to make a command that can kick all but all it does is print it can't kick my Bots name how would i fix this

@client.command()

async def kickall(ctx, *, reason=None):

```
if ctx.message.author.top_role.permissions.administrator:

    for member in ctx.guild.members:

            try:

                await member.kick(reason=reason)

                print(f"Kicked {member.name}")

            except:

                print(f"Could not kick {member}")

else:

    await ctx.send("Missing permissions.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The bot tries to kick itself and that doesn't work obviously.

members.remove(ctx.me)

Comment: Where would I add this into my code I'm a lil slow

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).